# Surface integral of a vector field equal to volume V

Tags: vector-fields, surface-integrals

Let V be a volume in  $\mathbb{R}^3$  bounded by a simple closed piecewise-smooth surface S with outward pointing normal vector **n**. For which one of the following vector fields is the surface integral $\iint\limits_{S}\mathbf{f}\cdot \mathbf{n}dS$ equal to the volume of V ?

**A:** $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})=(1,1,1)$

**B:** $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{2}(x,y,z)$

**C:** $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})=(2x,-y^2, 2yz-z)$

**D:** $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})=(z^2,y^2,1-2yz)$

**What I have tried:**

So for **A** and **D** I have worked out that the curl is $0$ so that rules those 2 out. I don't know how to tackle the other 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

For that, you need
$$\iint_S\vec{f}\cdot \vec{n}ds=\iiint_Vdxdydz$$

or simply that $$\nabla \cdot \vec{f}=1$$

For example, in the case $ C,$
$$\nabla \cdot (2x,-y^2,2yz-z)=$$
$$2-2y+2y-1=1$$

Comment: so it is equal to the volume if the divergence is 1? Hence the answer is **C**?

Comment: @Rox Yes exact {}{[{}{[{}{}. For $ B$ the divergence is $\frac 32$.